# SetState is not accepting a number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I'm new to react and I don't understand why I'm getting the following error while setting state on componentDidMount.  I did a research on similar errors, and I understand that react wants to be fed with a number, not with a promise. However, I'm pretty sure I'm resolving to a number by writing `.then(res => res.json().then(data => data)`. So I can't figure out where's the error from.

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in p (created by Info)
    in div (created by Info)
    in Info
```

This is the function that I use to fetch a number:

```
const get_eth = wallet =>
  fetch(
    `https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address=${wallet}&tag=latest`
  )
    .then(res =>
      res.json().then(data => data["result"] / 10 ** 18)
    )
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

And this is the setState:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({eth_q: get_eth("0x0975ca9f986eee35f5cbba2d672ad9bc8d2a0844")})
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: why don't you do a setState within promise resolve?     .then(res =>
      res.json().then(data => this.setState({eth_q: data["result"] / 10 ** 18))) . As in React anytime you update state the render triggers!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
const get_eth = wallet =>
  fetch(API)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => data["result"] / 10 ** 18)
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

That is, you're chaining `.then()` to your `.json()` instead of to your `fetch()`.

Then, in your `componentDidMount()`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  get_eth('0x0975ca9f986eee35f5cbba2d672ad9bc8d2a0844').then(res => {
    this.setState({ eth_q: res });
  });
}
```